# sustainsys.saml2 http handler doesn't redirect to sing on url in my ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, pingfederate, sustainsys-saml2

Instead of redirecting to "signOnUrl" my app redirects to the same login.aspx (start page) and I see Access Denied error. I use Pingfederate as Identity Provider. I have the following section in my web.config. I checked all the urls and they are available.

```
<sustainsys.saml2 entityId="..." returnUrl="..." authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Never">
    <nameIdPolicy allowCreate="true" format="Unspecified" />
    <requestedAuthnContext classRef="Password" comparison="Minimum" />
    <identityProviders>
        <add entityId="[metadata url]" signOnUrl="[soo endpoint]" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect" wantAuthnRequestsSigned="False">
            <signingCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findValue="[correct thumbprint]" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
        </add>
    </identityProviders>
</sustainsys.saml2>
```